# Find text in a string and prependTo somewhere else

Tags: jquery, regex, text, prepend

I am trying to find some text RegEx `/\w*http:[/][/]bit.ly[/]\w*/ig` that will find this string and pull it out, moving it to the `<span>` tag, or at the end of the `<p>` tag?

```
<p class="regex">Text before http://bit.ly/wtGAhsu sometext here, doesn't matter how long this is.... <span></span></p>
```

`$("p:regex('(\w*http:[/][/]bit.ly[/]\w*)')").addClass('active');`

Above is what I have so far (just selecting the p), I've tried `.highlight()` but Im not sure now to grab the text and move it, any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the output that you are expecting to match? From the question as it is right now, I can't understand what you are trying to extract.

Comment: I'm trying to find a specific link(which the regex works for) within a normal text paragraph and .detach it and move it to another position, either within the same string or somewhere else.

Comment: Hi James. This doesn't apply to just you, but in future could you please leave tags out of the title - it's what the actual tags are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
$("p.regex").each ( function () {
    var jThis   = $(this);
    var newSrc  = jThis.text ().replace (/^(.*)(https?\:\/\/bit\.ly\/\w+)(.*)$/i, '$1$3<span>$2</span>');
    jThis.html (newSrc);
} );
```

Note that this version assumes one link, max, per paragraph.

[**See it in action at jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/mwddb/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

HTML:

```
<div id="moveToArea"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$("p:regex('(\w*http:[/][/]bit.ly[/]\w*)')").addClass('active');
var item = $(".active")
$("$moveToArea").append(item, function(){
item.fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: The above is just highlighting the para .active?